# Adjusting margins between y-axis title and text when y-axis is on the right (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

First time posting, so sorry for any formalities I miss. I'm trying to adjust the margins between the y-axis title and text when the y-axis is positioned on the right side of the graph. Using 'margin = ' in 'element_text' seems to only work when the y axis is positioned on the left. Here is some sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10)) 

plot.y.left <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 20, 0, 0), 'mm')))
plot.y.left

plot.y.right <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 20), 'mm')))
plot.y.right
```

I've tried placing the 20 in different arguments (although I know it goes **t**op, **r**ight, **b**ottom, **l**eft), but it doesn't matter where you put the '20', the margins are always fixed in the same position. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Thanks for your help in advance

Cheers,

Comment: Use `axis.title.y.right` instead, it's a bit underdocumented but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use axis.title.y.right in theme instead

```
plot.y.right <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 20), 'mm')))

plot.y.right
```

Comment: Well THAT was easy! Thank you very much, worked liked a charm.